# Three.js - Camera collision with scene

Tags: three.js

This is my first question in StackOverflow, but I've been browsing it for some years now, so I kindly ask you to bear with me. :)

I've been experimenting with Three.js to create a 3D world, and everything looked fine until I needed to control the camera. Since I'm using this lib to avoid having to do matricial calculations myself I found and added TrackballControls to my code aswell. It worked fine but then my camera could pass through the 3D shapes, and also below terrain. Unfortunately, although the movement is **exactly** what I needed, it didn't serve the purpose of allowing camera to respect collision.

My scene is simply the ground (thin BoxGeometry) and a cube (normal-sized BoxGeometry), and a rotating sphere that shares directionalLight position for a "sun light" effect. Some people here suggested adding Physijs to the code and simulate() physics within the scene, and adding a BoxMesh to the camera to make the physics apply to it aswell, but it simply didn't work (scene turned blank).

My working code so far (without Physijs) is:

```
window.onload = function() {
        var renderer, scene, camera, ground, box, sphere, ambient_light, sun_light, controls;
        var angle = 0;
        var clock = new THREE.Clock();

        init();
        render();

        function init(){
            // Create renderer and add it to the page
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
            renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            // Create a scene to hold our awesome 3D world
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            /*** 3D WORLD ***/
            // Objects

            ground = new THREE.Mesh(
                new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 1, 50),
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x33CC33 }),
                0 // mass
            );

            ground.receiveShadow = true;
            scene.add( ground );

            box = new THREE.Mesh(
                new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10 ),
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xDD3344 })
            );

            box.position.y = 5;
            box.castShadow = true;

            scene.add( box );

            sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
                new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 32, 32 ),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFBB00 })
            );
            sphere.position.set( 1, 15.5, 5 );
            scene.add( sphere );

            // Light
            ambient_light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x333333 );
            ambient_light.mass = 0;
            scene.add( ambient_light );

            sun_light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xBBBBBB );
            sun_light.position.set( 1, 15.5, 5 );
            sun_light.castShadow = true;

            sun_light.shadowCameraNear = 1;
            sun_light.shadowCameraFar = 100;

            sun_light.shadowCameraLeft = -50;
            sun_light.shadowCameraRight = 50;
            sun_light.shadowCameraTop = -50;
            sun_light.shadowCameraBottom = 50;

            sun_light.shadowBias = -.01;

            scene.add( sun_light );

            // Create a camera
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
                45,                                     // FOV
                window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, // Aspect Ratio
                1,                                      // Near plane
                1000                                    // Far plane
            );
            camera.position.set( 30, 30, 30 ); // Position camera
            camera.lookAt( box.position ); // Look at the scene origin

            scene.add(camera);

            // After swapping THREE.Mesh to Physijs.BoxMesh, this is where I'd attach a BoxMesh to the camera

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
            controls.rotateSpeed = 4.0;
            controls.panSpeed = 0.3;
            controls.staticMoving = true; // No sliding after-effects

        }

        function render() {
            // use requestAnimationFrame to create a render loop
            angle += .007;
            var oscillateZ = Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI*4));
            var oscillateX = -Math.cos(angle * (Math.PI*4));
            //console.log(oscillateZ);
            sphere.position.setZ( sphere.position.z + oscillateZ );
            sphere.position.setX( sphere.position.x + oscillateX );
            sun_light.position.setZ( sun_light.position.z + oscillateZ );
            sun_light.position.setX( sun_light.position.x + oscillateX );

            requestAnimationFrame( render );
            controls.update();

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }

        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }
    };
```

Can you guys enlighten me? Thank you for your time!

@Edit
[Physijs attempt](http://pastebin.com/1rHvSTR2)

Comment: The Physijs approach is probably the way to go.
Could you post your code with Physijs as well? Maybe you just should've made the box transparent or you made an other simple mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Since jsfiddle has some issues with webworker, I'm posting the pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/1rHvSTR2

Thanks! :)

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Could you try changing the material of cameraMesh to new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff0000, transparent: true, opacity: 0.0});? Maybe that will help. If not can you post some screenshots here?

Comment: Changed material and it still displays the same: [Black thing](http://i.imgur.com/HUhL323.png)

Comment: There was a scoping issue (cameraMesh wasn't visible to render function), but I fixed by declaring it along the other variables. Still, the same black box shows up.

Comment: This box looks red, as the MeshLambertMaterial above.

Comment: This is the [updated code](http://pastebin.com/S9X1dQDL).